# Is there any activerecord translator for translating activerecord to SQL

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord, rubygems

I wanna check or know my the real SQL grammar generated by activerecord code, is there any gem or way can let me type the activerecord code and get the return equivalent SQL code?

EX :

```
Client.order(:first_name).first

#=> SELECT * FROM clients ORDER BY clients.first_name ASC LIMIT 1
```

Comment: Don't you see it in rails console?

Comment: No, but my rails console replaced by pry gem, does origin rails console has this function?

Comment: @Ruby Racer , oh I see the translation in rails console, but I. don't know if all the activerecord grammer can translate, I will check more

Comment: I do get the syntax in rails console.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Rails contains method `#to_sql`. But this is method of `ActiveRecord::Relation`. In your case code be like this:

```
Client.order(:first_name).limit(1).to_sql
```

You may read details in [documentation](http://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/Relation/to_sql).

Comment: This is also work but it only work in `ActiveRecord::Relation` as you say